# Trying to create user programmatically, running into issues

Tags: users

I'm attempting to programmatically create a user. I'd like to be able to create the user, then set the current global `$user` object to this newly created user. Here is what my code looks like.

```
    $new_user = array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['username'],
        'pass' => $form_state['values']['password'],
        'mail' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'status' => 1,
        'init' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'roles' => array(
            DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user'
        )
    );

    if ($saved_user = user_save(NULL, $new_user)){
        user_load($saved_user->uid, TRUE);
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'member/profile';
    } else {
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'member/join';
    }
```

The reason for me essentially wrapping the existing user page is that there is a lot of additional functionality needed. This code does create a user in the database, but it fails in two places: 1) It does not create any roles for this new user in the `users_roles` table, and 2) It does not log the current user in or adjust the global `$user` object.

Any ideas why this is failing?

EDIT: Using Drupal 7.9

EDIT2: I solved the user not being logged in issue by using the function `user_login_submit`. Roles still aren't creating correctly, however.

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified - Drupal 7.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user_save()` does nothing with roles unless they're part of the `$account` object (first argument passed in). Stepping through the code I can't see any reason why simply setting up a dummy `$account` var to pass in, just containing the roles, wouldn't work:

```
$new_user = array(
    'name' => $form_state['values']['username'],
    'pass' => $form_state['values']['password'],
    'mail' => $form_state['values']['email'],
    'status' => 1,
    'init' => $form_state['values']['email']
);

$account = new stdClass;
$account->roles = array(
  DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user'
);

if ($saved_user = user_save($account, $new_user)) {
  // etc...
```

`user_save()` seems to do all the rest of the required setup on the `$account` object so this should work fine.

Comment: While your solution should work fine, I have code that sets the roles on the $new_user and it works without any problems.

Comment: @kummel You must be setting them on the `$account` object as well...have a look at the code for [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7), specifically the bit which says `if (count($account->roles) > 1) {`. If `$account->roles` isn't set, no roles will ever be written to the database

Comment: No, I'm not -> user_save(null, $new); No account object. Later on in the user_save than the bit you're pointing to it loops the $new data and sets it on $account. `foreach ($edit as $key => $value) { $account->$key = $value; }`
So something else must be going wrong.

Comment: If that were true then simply adding an `$account` object with  a `roles` property wouldn't fix the problem (as it would be overwritten by the loop you've posted), but the OP has confirmed the above has fixed the problem.

Comment: sorry, the loop happens before the code you're pointing to, not after.

Comment: @kummel Yes, but *after* passing the `$account` object into the function; hence my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal's anonymous and authenticated roles don't get saved in the users_roles table and you don't need to add the role yourself, all users are by default authenticated. Try editing your user in the backend, you'll see that it has authenticated checked off.
The code you list above where you send the roles array in the $edit will work fine with any other role.